# Remove the Filter in Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure-storage-explorer

How can I remove the filter in Azure Storage Explorer from automatically displaying?  Every time I right click on a blob and open a new tab to display my folders and files, the filter takes up half the screen space. I find it much easier to type in the address bar than to navigate with the filter.  I know I can hide it by clicking the filter icon, but how can I make the default to not show the filter?  It is always in the way for seeing file size, and other information.

I tried searching through all the settings and preferences, and I didn't find anything related to panel layout with respect to the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are referring about this:

[image]

This is such an interesting question, because the default behavior is that this control does not show by default. So if it is for the you that means they’ve modified the setting which controls the behavior in the past. In any case, the setting can be found under:

**Settings > Data Explorers > Blob Explorer > Show View Options By Default**

In general, any setting which is related to a behavior in one of the data explorers (views on the right hand side used for exploring data) can be found under **Settings > Data Explorers**, with settings specific to certain data explorers (such as the blob data explorer) having their own category underneath **Data Explorers.**

Comment: This fixed my issue! The settings term "Show View Options By Default" didn't stand out to me when I was trying to read through the settings and find something related to the filter.